# Weird indefinite integral situation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider the integral $$\int\frac{x}{x^4+3x^2+2}dx=\int\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2+(x^2+1)}dx$$ Here we make a change of variable $x^2+1=t$ so our integral becomes $$\frac12\int\frac{dt}{t(t+1)}=\frac12\int\frac{dt}{t}-\frac12\int\frac{dt}{t+1}=\frac{1}{2}\ln|x^2+1|-\frac12|x^2+2|+C$$ The integral evaluator at [this site](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) evaluates this integral as $$\arctan(x)-\frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt2})}{\sqrt2}$$ Now there is no problem that the function I obtained differs from the one obtained by the calculator, however I do find it problematic that they have different **graphs** as you can see [here.](http://pokit.org/get/?405efd6b21969853f7ab66f64075d701.jpg) Nevertheless, both functions when derived give the same starting function.

How is it possible that one function has two *different* antiderivatives (not simply differing for a constant) ?

Comment: the arctan one is wrong I think - where is the x in the numerator coming from if it is differentiated - not sat down with pen and papar though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a typo because when I enter your integral at the [integral evaluator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/), it gives me your answer. Note however that ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20(arctan(x)-arctan(x%2Fsqrt(2))%2Fsqrt(2)))):
$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x} \left( \arctan(x)-\frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt2})}{\sqrt2}\right) = \frac{\color{blue}{1}}{x^4+3x^2+2} \color{red}{\ne} \frac{\color{blue}{x}}{x^4+3x^2+2}$$so you probably simply forgot the $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int{x \over x^{4} + 3x^{2} + 2}\,\dd x & =
\int{x \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x - \int{x \over x^{2} + 2}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{x^{2} + 1} - {1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{x^{2} + 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{x^{2} + 1 \over x^{2} + 2} + 
\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}
\end{align}